# Why does the on screen keyboard doesn't work on password field, but my physical keyboard works?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, selenium, web

How will I able to automate this `<object>` field or input a text not using a physical keyboard in selenium or in C#

```
<object width="200" height="24" id="safeEdit1" classid="CLSID:73E4740C-08EB-4133-896B-8D0A7C9EE3CD" codebase="/icbc/newperbank/AxSafeControls.cab#version=1,0,0,30" style="vertical-align: middle;" onkeyup="getfocus1('verifyCodeCn', event);" onfocus="clearErrTip();detectCapsLock('logonform','safeEdit1',670,140,400,'logontb')" onblur="closeCapTip('logonform','safeEdit1')"><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="5292"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="635">
<param name="name" value="logonCardPass">
<param name="minLength" value="4">
<param name="maxLength" value="30">
<param name="rule" value="10111">
<param name="UniqueID" value="1577983525102276921">
<param name="IsPassword" value="true">
<param name="prompttext" value="登录密码">
<param name="prompttextcolor" value="102,102,102">
<param name="backgroundcolor" value="255,255,255">
<param name="isbordervisible" value="0">
<param name="CryptAlg" value="2">
<param name="ruleName" value="ruleName">
<param name="changeRuleName" value="changeRuleName">
</object>
```

I am using selenium, I also used InputSimulator but it doesn't work.

I am using this on Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Does it work with any other browser? Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: No, it doesn't work on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

Comment: where is input tag?

Comment: <input name="logonCardPass_cryptAlg" type="hidden" value="1">

Comment: But it doesn't work also. When I use selenium to modify safeEdit1 the field is only blinking.

Comment: is it possible for you to share url?

Comment: https://mybank.icbc.com.cn/icbc/newperbank/perbank3/frame/frame_index.jsp

Comment: use IE because the other browsers won't work.

Comment: Off topic: but why even use time on directx now? Ie is the only browser support it and ie is really old now. By the way, the error cause might be because of ie settings, not code

Comment: This is ActiveX not directx, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this relies on mimicking the user input. We used Robot Java + Masking Input Events and Threading to implement this on C#.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(1000, 470);
int mask = java.awt.@event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK;
robot.keyPress(java.awt.@event.KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Comment: You can also use robot tab to enter values here.